# Cannot load JSON files into python

Tags: python, json, parsing, import, load

I have been trying to load a json file into python by using the module `json`
But my json file contains some data's of different language (except english)

```
[
    {
      "english_name": "Malayalam",
      "iso_639_1": "ml",
      "name": ""
    },
    {
      "english_name": "Tamil",
      "iso_639_1": "ta",
      "name": "தமிழ்"
    }
]
```

This is a part of my JSON file.You can see that my JSON file contains varied language.
I suppose this is the problem for getting a error while running the code

```
import json
file = open('./DummyData/movie_details.json')
data = json.load(file)
print(data)
file.close()
```

Error

```
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 540: character maps to <undefined>
```

Please tell how to remove the unwanted item or just load without any errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `encoding` parameter in the `open` function. It will accept all languages.

```py
file = open("./main.json", "r", encoding="utf-8")
```